# How do Torch 7 load very large datasets that do not fit in memory?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, torch

I have some very large datasets which I want to load into Torch. But I cannot load them fully to the memory before I run my learning algorithm.

What should I do to maximize performance?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to work with a subset of your original data set?

Comment: Yes, but would it be too slow? Every time  for a mini batch it has to wait for slow I/O. Will a buffer help?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Torch.  Tools like R and MATLAB operate in memory.  So there is a penalty to read in data sets, but after this it is smooth sailing.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [imagenet-multiGPU.torch](https://github.com/soumith/imagenet-multiGPU.torch) full-stack sample code. It contains a data loader (`dataset.lua`) able to sample a batch of images at a time which prevents from pre-loading everything in memory:

```
local inputs, labels = trainLoader:sample(opt.batchSize)
```

(see [`train.lua`](https://github.com/soumith/imagenet-multiGPU.torch/blob/64872bf5d5c86ce0c7beb3fd7e148b6f19959437/train.lua#L94-L105) for more details)